# Keeping the text in a java textField always selected

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

While processing output from a java textField, I require to keep the input text always selected. The code I wrote works perfectly except  keeping the text in it always selected. Kindly help me to amend the code so that text in the textField  always remains selected. I have used ' textField.selectAll();', but it does not work here.

```
private class ButtonClickListener implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();  
        if( command.equals( "OK" )) {  

            String text = textField.getText();
            textField.selectAll(); 
            textArea.append(text + newline); 

            System.out.print(text);

            //Make sure the new text is visible, even if there
            //was a selection in the text area.
            textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: i don't understand your question very well? you want that the text being selected even if the user input a new value? if it's that you can use a `DocumentListener` to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Add a [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) to the text document, then the text always will be selected even if the user remove or insert a value.

```
textfield.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
     @Override
     public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
         textfield.selectAll();
     }   

     @Override
     public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
         textfield.selectAll();
     } 

     @Override
     public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
      //nothing to do..
     }

});
```

Read more in [How to wirte a Document Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)

Comment: Hi nachokk,lot of thanks, so let I try you said. If there will be any problem, then I shall be back here.

Comment: @nachokk textField = new JTextField(20);
        textField.addActionListener(new ButtonClickListener());
        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
     Override
     public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
         textField.selectAll();
     }   

     Override
     public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
         textField.selectAll();
     } 

      Override
     public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
      //nothing to do..
     }

     });     (Hi I have tried this way, no error by compiler, but it did not work as required.)

Comment: @ nachokk, Sorry as the above comment has become messy and over-crowded, I do not know what  is the best way to submit the code through this AddComment window at such need.

Comment: @HarjitSingh What is the problem with this code? How is not working as you expected? You need it to be selectable even if you are not in focus?