# Java in actionPerformed cannot add to arrayList, result is "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java

Thanks!  This problem is solved by new ArrayList.
phrases = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(s));

First, thank-you stackoverflow.com, for having such good information and help!
Below is my minimum failing case.  I am running java jdk 1.7.0_60 from a cygwin window
on Windows 7.  The problem is line 60 inside `actionPerformed` where I try to do:
`phrases.add("QUIT;");`  where phrases is an array list.  Although work-around is to
append `QUIT` to `JTextArea`, I would like to understand why the `phrases.add()` does not
work.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Collections;

class MFC extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JTextArea myTextArea = new JTextArea(12, 30);

    //same result if public or private
    private List<String> phrases = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(
            "Type or paste your SQL here","quit;"));

    MFC() {
        super("List<String>");
        setSize(370, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT);
        setLayout(flow);
        JPanel row1 = new JPanel();

        myTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
        myTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        // initialize the text area from initial phrases
        for(int i=0; i < phrases.size(); i++) {
           myTextArea.append(phrases.get(i) + "\n");
        }
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701113/keeping-the-text-in-a-java-textfield-always-selected
        //Make sure the new text is visible, even if there
        //was a selection in the text area.
        myTextArea.setCaretPosition(myTextArea.getDocument().getLength());

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(myTextArea,
           JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
           JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        row1.add(scroll);
        add(row1);
        JPanel row2 = new JPanel();
        JButton execute = new JButton("Execute");
        execute.addActionListener(this);
        row2.add(execute);
        add(row2);
        setVisible(true);
    } // end MFC()

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        myTextArea.append("QUIT;");                      //this works
        String s[] = myTextArea.getText().split("\\n");  //this works
        phrases = Arrays.asList(s);                      //this works

        dump();

        /*** THIS IS THE STATEMENT NOT WORKING ***/
        phrases.add("QUIT;");                     // NOT WORKING

       dump();

    }//end actionPerformed()

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        MFC mfc = new MFC();
    }

    void dump() {
        System.out.println("phrases.size() is " + phrases.size());
        Iterator iterator1 = phrases.iterator();   // single use
        while (iterator1.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Phrase " + iterator1.next());  // works
        }
    }
}//end MFC class
```

Here is the result:

```
$ java MFC
phrases.size() is 5
Phrase abc
Phrase def
Phrase 123
Phrase 456
Phrase QUIT;
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
        at MFC.actionPerformed(MFC.java:60)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Answer (score 1):

You've assigned your `List` variable `phrases` to [`Arrays.asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) which returns a fixed size `List`

```
phrases = Arrays.asList(s);
```

Since elements can be added to an `ArrayList` you could just use

```
phrases = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(s));
```

as you did originally.

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList()` doesn't create a new list, really.  It gives you an object that acts like a `List`, but really just accesses the array.  Since you can't make an array larger by adding elements to it, you can't append to this kind of list, either.

Instead of

```
phrases = Arrays.asList(s);
```

try

```
phrases = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s));
```

which does create a new list, and initializes it by copying the elements of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Read [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29):

> public static  List asList(T... a)
>
> Returns a **fixed-size** list backed by the specified array.

(emphasis mine)